# Using conditions in Phalcon MongoDB (ODM)

Tags: php, mongodb, phalcon

I would like to retrieve records which has enddate 'lesser' than "today". Below is what i come out with, but does not work. Any advice appreciated.

```
$records = Records::find(array(
        '$lte' => array(
            array( 'endDateTime' =>  date())
        ),
        "limit" => 10,
        "sort"  => array("_id" => -1)
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested it to be honest, but I think this should do the trick:

```
$records = Records::find(array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'endDateTime' => array(
            '$lte' => new Mongodate(strtotime("now"))
        ),
    ),
    'limit' => 10,
    'sort'  => array(
        '_id' => -1
    )
));
```